# Summary of a Subset in R does not work - Why?

Tags: r, subset

I am doing the Analytics Edge course on EdX and ran into this problem. We have a dataset which we are subsetting. Running a Str on the subset works as intended, however trying summary on the same subset throws an error. Can someone explain why?

```
> str(WHO_Europe)
'data.frame':   53 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Country                      : Factor w/ 194 levels "Afghanistan",..: 2 4 8 10 11 16 17 22 26 42 ...
 $ Region                       : Factor w/ 6 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Population                   : int  3162 78 2969 8464 9309 9405 11060 3834 7278 4307 ...
 $ Under15                      : num  21.3 15.2 20.3 14.5 22.2 ...
 $ Over60                       : num  14.93 22.86 14.06 23.52 8.24 ...
 $ FertilityRate                : num  1.75 NA 1.74 1.44 1.96 1.47 1.85 1.26 1.51 1.48 ...
 $ LifeExpectancy               : int  74 82 71 81 71 71 80 76 74 77 ...
 $ ChildMortality               : num  16.7 3.2 16.4 4 35.2 5.2 4.2 6.7 12.1 4.7 ...
 $ CellularSubscribers          : num  96.4 75.5 103.6 154.8 108.8 ...
 $ LiteracyRate                 : num  NA NA 99.6 NA NA NA NA 97.9 NA 98.8 ...
 $ GNI                          : num  8820 NA 6100 42050 8960 ...
 $ PrimarySchoolEnrollmentMale  : num  NA 78.4 NA NA 85.3 NA 98.9 86.5 99.3 94.8 ...
 $ PrimarySchoolEnrollmentFemale: num  NA 79.4 NA NA 84.1 NA 99.2 88.4 99.7 97 ...
> Summary(WHO_Europe)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Summary’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
> write.csv(WHO_Europe,"WHO_Europe.CSV")
> Summary(WHO_Europe)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Summary’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

Comment: You need `summary()` (lower-case `s`), not `Summary`.

Comment: Shoot, you are right! Thanks!

Comment: R is case-sensitive.